# Querying click events in google ad campaign

Tags: oauth2-playground

We are utilizing the Outh 2.0 playground and getting this error:

"authorizationError": "DEVELOPER_TOKEN_PROHIBITED"
},
"message": "Developer token is not allowed with project '407408718192'."

We are trying to figure out click reporting prior to going live.

We are trying to run this endpoint:
https://googleads.googleapis.com/v14/customers:listAccessibleCustomers

We tried to authorize the developer token for this admin account but we are not ready to provide all the required information. Is there anyway to test this in advance. Or can anyone send us further documentation? Thanks in advance.